# Rappasoft/LaravelLivewireDatatables Show filters by default

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

So I'm working on a JobTable which I'm using rappasoft datatables to handle, the main reason for using this package is it works with tailwind and darkmode also works both of which are key to this projects requirements. So far pretty good I have the table generating and bar some columns not sorting all alse is doing as it should. At the top of the view is a button that says filters and by clicking this the 2 dropdowns we need are shown. What i wish is to have these dropdowns shown by default without the button needing to be clicked:
[image]

and when the Filters button is clicked i see the result I want by default:
[image]

Not sure what code would be needed but here is the configure function that has the setFilterLayoutSlideDown() function:

```
    public function configure(): void
    {
        $this->setPrimaryKey('number')
            ->setReorderDisabled()
            ->setSortingEnabled()
            ->setDefaultSort('number', 'desc')
            ->setSingleSortingDisabled()
            ->setSortingPillsEnabled()
            ->setHideReorderColumnUnlessReorderingEnabled()
            ->setRememberColumnSelectionEnabled()
            ->setFilterLayoutSlideDown()
            ->setSecondaryHeaderTrAttributes(function($rows) {
                return ['class' => 'bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800'];
            })
            ->setSecondaryHeaderTdAttributes(function(Column $column, $rows) {
                if ($column->isField('number')) {
                    return ['class' => 'text-red-500'];
                }

                return ['default' => true];
            })
            ->setFooterTrAttributes(function($rows) {
                return ['class' => 'bg-gray-100'];
            })
            ->setFooterTdAttributes(function(Column $column, $rows) {
                if ($column->isField('name')) {
                    return ['class' => 'text-green-500'];
                }

                return ['default' => true];
            })
            ->setUseHeaderAsFooterEnabled()
            ->setBulkActionsEnabled();
    }
```